# How to match text before the first hyphen

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
Citas de Esopo - Música - Belleza...
Citas de Lem, Stanislaw - Tortura, sueño...
```

And I need to extract "Esopo" from the first one and "Lem, Stanislaw" from the 2nd. I have the following regex wich works great for the second case:

```
/Citas de (.*) \-(.*)\.\.\./
```

But for the fist case it returns "Esopo - Música". How can I write the regex so it matches the text before the first "-" appearance?

I use preg_match and then the first array position of the matches

```
 if( preg_match($pattern, $title, $result) > 0 )
 {
     $title = $result[1];
 }
```

Comment: Regex is greedy. You have to tell it what it cannot munch up. `.` says it can munch on anything. You want `[^-]` to tell it that it can only munch on anything that is not a dash/hyphen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `?` (as less as possible) to your solution.

```
/Citas de (.*?) \-(.*)\.\.\./
```

Here is the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1aT2/2).

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
\bCitas de\h+([^-]+)\h+
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mZ1aT2/1)

**Code:**

```
if ( preg_match_all(/\bCitas de\h+([^-]+)\h+/, $input, $matches) )
   print_r($matches[1]);
```